# RDC through VPN not working on 1 particular computer

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop, windows-11

I am remote worker and my working environment is set up this way :

- I use Cisco AnyConnect client to connect to my company's VPN.
- then I use *Remote Desktop Connection* to connect to my virtual machine (Windows) inside my company's network.
- I work on my remote Windows.

I have 3 different computers which I use for connecting to my remote machine, all with Windows 11 pro. 2 of them work flawlessly, and the 3rd one, my favorite laptop, fails frequently lately (it worked pretty fine before).
It always connects to VPN, but RDC sometimes fails to connect, and sometimes it connects but later it breaks and fails to connect again. The message being shown seems useless : *Remote Desktop can't find the computer "xyz". This might mean that "xyz" does not belong to the specified network.  Verify the computer name and domain that you are trying to connect to."*. Trying to connect again usually does not work (though sometimes it does), no matter if I just try again, or restart VPN connection or my Windows meanwhile.
Administrators from my company have no idea what could be happening. It's obviously all fine on their side.
Have you got any idea what may I check ?

Comment: That error sounds like your computer has some DNS problems on the VPN. See if you can resolve the xyz name in cmd? Run `nslookup xyz` and/or `nslookup xyz.domain.com` (if those fail, make sure the Server address it shows is a company one). Can you connect RDP using the VM's IP address?

Comment: Well, nslookup works, and returns the ip address. Connection using ip address works now, while connection using vm name does not work. This might be the solution, I'll see what happens these days. Thanks!